# MPAndroidChart LineChart begin at the last x value

Tags: android-studio, mpandroidchart, linechart

I'm trying to use moveViewToX to show a chart starting from the last x value, so the user drags the chart to see older data. But it does not move exactly where I expected, I'm moving to the value 2.013 but it's starting before it, then I can't see my last x value which is 2.018. Take a look at the images for better understanding.

[image showing what's happening] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0Z4f.png

[image showing what I expected to happen][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3JhM.png

Here's the part of the code that modifies LineChart

```
mLineChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
mLineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
mLineChart.getXAxis().setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
mLineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(5);
mLineChart.getXAxis().setGranularity(1);
mLineChart.moveViewToX(2013);
mLineChart.invalidate();
```

I'd appreaciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `dragOffsetX`, otherwise the chart will not allow you to move past the end of the last value on the x axis.

You can also try specifying the axis maximum:

```
mLineChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaximum(lastValue + 5)
```